# Ruby on Rails Edit and Delete post comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, pins

Hi i am trying to add comments to my Pins Model . I can add comments but i cant seem to get the right link for my Edit and Delete actions.

comments controller

```
            class CommentsController < ApplicationController
                before_action :find_pin
                before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]
                def index

                end

                def show

                end

                def new
                  @comment = Comment.new
                end

                def create

                    @comment = @pin.comments.build(comment_params)
                    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

                    @comment.save

                    if @comment.save
                        flash[:notice] = "Created comment"
                        redirect_to pin_url(@pin.id)
                    else
                        render 'new'
                    end


                end

                def edit

                end

            def update
            @comment = @pin.comments.find(params[:id])
              end

              def destroy

                @comment.destroy
                flash[:notice] = "Deleted Comment"
                redirect_to pin_url(@pin.id)
              end


            private


                def find_pin

                @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
                end

                def find_comment

                    @comment = Comments.find(params[:pin_id])

                end

                def comment_params
                    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
                end
            end
```

comments form view

```
            <%= form_for ([@comment.build]) do |f| %>
                <p><%= f.text_area :content %></p>

                <p><%= f.submit %></p>
            <% end %>
```

comments show view

```
        <%= @comment.each do |comment| %>

            <p><%= comment.content %></p>


            <% if current_user == comment.user %>
            <%= link_to "Edit comment", edit_comment_path(@pin, comment)%>
            <%= link_to "Delete comment", [comment.pin,comment], method: :delete  %>
            <% end %>




        <% end %>
```

routes

```
         Rails.application.routes.draw do
          match '/users',   to: 'users#index',   via: 'get'
          match '/users/:id',     to: 'users#show',       via: 'get'




          get 'homes/show'

          devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
          resources  :pins do
            member do
              resources :comments
              put "like",    to: "pins#upvote"
            end
          end
          resources :users, :only =>[:show]

          root "pins#index"
        end
```

pins controller

```
                 class PinsController < ApplicationController
                        before_action :find_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
                        before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

                        def index
                            @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")

                        end

                        def show

                            @comment= Comment.where(pin_id: @pin).order("created_at DESC") 

                        end


                        def new
                            @pin = current_user.pins.build
                        end

                        def create
                            @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

                            if @pin.save
                                redirect_to @pin, notice: "Successfully created new Pin"
                            else
                                render 'new'
                            end
                        end

                        def edit
                            if @pin.user != current_user
                           redirect_to root_path
                        end
                        end

                        def update
                            if @pin.update(pin_params) && @pin.user == current_user
                             redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin was successfully updated"
                        else
                           render 'edit'
                         end
                        end

                        def destroy
                            if @pin.user == current_user
                            @pin.destroy
                            redirect_to root_path
                             else
                             redirect_to root_path, notice: "Not Your Pin!"
                             end    
                        end

                        def upvote
                            @pin.upvote_by current_user
                            redirect_to :back
                        end


                        private

                        def pin_params
                            params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image)
                        end

                        def find_pin
                            @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
                        end
                    end
```

thanks in advance ive been stuck on this for awhile
for some reason the pins id and comments id end up the same or something
http://localhost:3000/pins/30/comments/30

Comment: Since you have nested resources in your routes, the model name of the parent resource will be prefixed to the path helper method. I.e. `pin_comment_path`.

Comment: ok still learning, whats my next step what should i use for the edit comment link_ to "<%= link_to "Edit comment"," ?

Comment: i know ill be rebuilding this eventually lol. just want to get something to show for my countless hours lol

Answer (score 1):

Run `rake routes` to check all the routes you have in your app. You would find that all routes would be named in plural. So `edit_pins_comments_path` will only be present for your application. But as your models suggest, each pin will be having many comments. to accomplish this you need to nest your comment resource into each member of pins. So your routes will become like below.

```
resources  :pins do
  member do
    resources :comments
    put "like",    to: "pins#upvote"
    put "favorite",   to: "pins#favorite"
  end
end
```

This code will generate `edit_comment_path`, `comment_path` etc.